# Java Card Local Fixed-Size Array Variable Memory Storage Location

Tags: smartcard, javacard

I wonder if anyone knows exactly where is `temp` array stored (EEPROM or RAM) in the following Java Card method (part of source code of WalletDemoApplet I have found inside JCIDE samples directory) . Please note that the array is not allocated by means of makeTransientByteArray. Also it is declared as a local variable inside a method.

```
private void calIntegral(byte [] buf,byte soff,short len)
{
    byte temp[]={0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
    short low=0;
    byte aa=0;
    if (len==2)
        Util.arrayCopy(buf, soff, temp,(short)2, len);
    else
        Util.arrayCopy(buf, soff, temp,(short)0, len);

    ...
}
```

Also, in the [Java Card Applet Developer's Guide](ftp://ftp.icm.edu.pl/packages/javasoft-docs/javacard/JCADG.pdf), you can find:

> The Converter ensures that memory is allocated for the contents of static fields, namely, primitive data types
>   and references to arrays. Memory is allocated for instances by using the new bytecode from the system heap
>   and cannot be reclaimed (unless the smart card implements a garbage collector). Memory for method
>   variables, locals, and parameters is allocated from the stack and is reclaimed when the method returns.

Comment: The demo is being looked at by the good people at JavaCardOS as we speak; there may be other bugs (I sent a link to the Q/A)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This part of the `WalletDemoApplet` should certainly not be generated in a local variable:

```
byte temp[]={0x00,0x00,0x00,0x00};
```

That's EEPROM storage; the `new byte[]` part may be hidden, but the array creation is still performed, [as specified by the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.3):

> An array initializer creates an array and provides initial values for all its components.

here the array initializer is the braces and anything within it.

---

Please ignore at least that part of the example. Generally you would use a static method for that, and using a class field with `makeTransientByteArray` (called during instantiation of the Applet) as buffer. That is: if you require an array, simply defining 4 byte variables or - in this case - directly setting byte values could work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Any Array will be created in `EEPROM`, that is not created with `makeTransientByteArray`. You can check available and consumed memory in `JCIDE` tool. 
In this example memory will be assign again and again in `EEPROM`, when this methods will be called.